# JSF Render a SelectOneRadio with a PanelGrid

Tags: jsf

I need to render the following form:

[image]

One Radio must be followed by Data (in panel grid).

SelectOneRadio is rendered using an html table, and PanelGrid is also redered using owned html table.

Can somebody help me to build this form using JSF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a problem by nesting tables. The following code would produce a similar output:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="empty-cells:show">
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.selectedRadioValue}" >
        <f:selectItem value="selected" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <h:outputText value="Numero de boelta: #{bean.numero}" />
    <h:outputText value="Monto transaccion" />
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.transaccion}" />
    <h:outputText value="Description" />
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.description}" />
    <h:outputText value="Factura" />
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.factura}" />
    <h:outputText value="Abonado" />
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.abonado" />
    <h:outputText value="Nombre" />
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.nombre}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

If you have problems nesting componetns as 1 component in the panelGrid you can always encapsulate them in a h:panelGroup. The panelGroup will make two or more components nest them as one.